# Remove pre-loaded class when another div is selected

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

I have a row of 3 divs which are highlighted on hover.

I have the first one highlighted on page load but the class does not remove when you hover over one of the other two.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I remove the class when I select another one?

https://codepen.io/sharpy24ws/pen/ExxMGgW

```
  var header = document.getElementById("myDIV row");
  var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
  }
```

Comment: Are you using jquery? In this? or could you?

Comment: Jquery will be used elsewhere on the page it it going on, so that would be fine if I could get it to work. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `.card1 {}` rule at the bottom of your CSS file, as I think it makes more sense to simply add the `.active` onto the card's HTML

The card mouseover listener is using jQuery's `.hover()` - The first callback is the mouse*over* function, the second is the mouse*leave*

I've also fixed your selector for `header`, and made the selector for `card` a little more robust - `[id*="card"]` is using the attribute selector to return only divs that have an `ID` that starts with 'card'

```js
const $header = $("#myDIV#row");
const $card = $('div[id*="card"]');

$card.hover(function () {
  $(this).addClass('active');
}, function () {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.card {

  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */

.active,
.btn:hover {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  background-color: #fff;

}

.cardheaderimage {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.cardheadertext {
  color: #001F55;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #001F55;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.catdmaintext {
  color: #001F55;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cardlinktext {
  color: #30A3FC;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 88px;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*
.card1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122, 113, 122, 0.66);
  background-color: #fff;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="inner">
      <div id="myDIV row" class="row no-margin ">

        <div class="card card1 col-4 active" id="card1">
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 1</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text
              here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>


        <div class="card col-4" id="card2">
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 2</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text
              here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>


        <div class="card col-4" id="card3">
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 3</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text
              here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="qu-container" style="display: none;"><a href="#" class="qu-btn w-button active"
      onClick="validateForm('Request_More_Information')">Request more information</a>
  </div>
  <div class="qu-container" style="display: none;"><a href="#" class="qu-btn w-button active"
      onClick="validateForm('Request_More_Information')">Request more information</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove the `.active` class from the first box, which is also styled via `.card1` class that you do not remove.

You may set this .active class right in the html, so it can be removed on hover . remove also the css rules for `.card1` .

example:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV row");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.card {
  
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
 height: auto;
 border: 0;
}
/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */

.active, .btn:hover {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122,113,122,0.66);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122,113,122,0.66);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(122,113,122,0.66);
background-color: #fff;
  
}

.cardheaderimage
{
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.cardheadertext
{
color: #001F55;
font-size: 1.8em;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #001F55;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.catdmaintext
{
color: #001F55;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-bottom: 20px;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
text-decoration:none;
}

.cardlinktext
{
color: #30A3FC;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-bottom: 88px;
font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="inner">
      <div id="myDIV row" class="row no-margin ">        
        <div class="card card1 col-4 active" id="card1"> 
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 1</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-4" id="card2">
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 2</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-4" id="card3">
          <center>
            <div class="cardheadertext">Panel 3</div>
            <div class="catdmaintext">Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br> Panel body text here. <br></div>
            <div class="cardlinktext"><a href="#">Click Here...</a></div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and answers. That works great.